# Looking for ideas to implement an anonymous Suggestion Box in Drupal

Tags: drupal

I have a need to allow authenticated users to create content in Drupal anonymously.  Ideally something like a Suggestion Box.  The suggestion should have no fingerprint of who submitted it and ideally it should be submitted but not published until it is reviewed and approved.

Looking at the contact form and other modules, I haven't been able to get a clear direction on how to do this.  Ideally I would think that at submission, I'd like to override the Authored By field and set this to anonymous.  Is this the right direction or can I create a simple form that would be emailed to someone without ever creating a node?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest just creating a form using [webform](http://drupal.org/project/webform) module.

Comment: Webform got me close to the final answer.  However, I could not see a way to turn off the WebForm collecting the results to a table.  In this table was included the name of the submitter.  In the email result I was able to remove the submitter, but I then had to deal with that table.  I used a MySQL trigger such that on insert it set the user id field to 1, the id of the main user.  The only problem this then creates is that I can't easily mix anonymous and submitted forms preserving the id of the user.

Comment: you could create a quick module that defines a table and writes the id of the form submission and the role of the user to that table.

Comment: more simply: you should be able to create a hidden field and write the user role to the field.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want a node, just create a simple php form that sends a `mail()` on completion. You will need to enable the PHP filter and then just create a page with the PHP form in the content area.

If you wanted a node, you could create a custom content type called suggestions and then use a custom module to remove the author tag using `hook_form_alter`.

```
function uofm_usertasks_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

  switch($form_id)
  {
    case 'suggestion_node_form':
      $form['authored']['name']['#access'] = FALSE; // not sure if this is the right item in the form or not
      break;
  }

}
```